# EventLogFile : How can we see how many times a user clicks on a hyperlink

Tags: lightning-events, eventlogfile, event-monitoring

On our Account object we have a custom formula field that spits out a hyper link to the user. When the user clicks the link they are directed to a custom lighting component.

Using the EventLogFile object, how do we search for the events when the user clicks on the link?

Custom Formula used on field is:

```
HYPERLINK(
   "<*company_name*>.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/<*compoennt_name*>c__recordId=" + Id,
   "Click to Enter"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_download) it has steps to access the event log. Then Filter with Event Type **URI Event Type** once you download all the CSV's you can filter on your URI to see how many times it was accessed.

Comment: URI events are also available now in Real Time Monitoring and you can use SOQL to query for data up to 6 mo old

Comment: We can get at the data via Splunk but are unsure what fields we should filter by to get to the clicks on that link. Any clue what the attributes we should filter on? When we filter the URI where contains the component name, we get all the events that involve the component, not just the link clicks.